# NativeMessaging in Android inside chromebook

Tags: android, chromebook, chrome-native-messaging

I came with a weird question but sadly I don;'t have any code example to base me on.

I'm trying to create an android application that uses [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/)
to communicate with a google chrome extension. That application will be running as android application in the same chromebook as the chrome extension will be running.

Is that even possible? I questioniung because of native messaging uses standard input output to communicate and android also does it for logcat and I think is not actually the same I/O I need because of the VM of android..

So, does anyone know if is that possible? Do you have any other way to do it? I've tried with websockets and it worked but sadly, chrome complains about the ssl certificate because is self signed and the websocket is not running in localhost but in ARC chromebook IP.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible.
It is possible to do native messaging using Python or nodejs on Chromebook Linux.

Comment: Do you have an example? I could use it in python or nodejs and bind it to android someway else.